# Sharing images to social media - issue with aspect ratio

Tags: images, facebook, social-sharing

I am designing a website that will have a lot of images, and I want those images to be shareable to Facebook.

I know this is possible with social media plugins like "Easy Social Share Buttons," where you can hover over the image and the social media icons appear.

BUT, when you share the image, it gets posted to Facebook like a regular link share - it becomes a featured image with a 2:1 aspect ratio (or a thumbnail) and a link to the website.

Most of my images will be vertical (or at worst, 1:1), and I want to share the full image in its original aspect ratio on Facebook. If my image is not already at that 2:1 ratio, it chops off the top and bottom of the image when sharing to Facebook.

Is there a plugin that allows me to share the entire image? Perhaps by sharing the content to Facebook as an image and not a link?

OR, is it possible to develop a plugin that would do this?

The demo for a plugin called "Monarch" is a good example of how the hover icons share the content as a link rather than an image (click the link below and share the image about two-thirds down the page to Facebook.)

Example: https://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Monarch/media-sharing/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This has also been my long time problem. I would also prefer a zoomed out version of the entire image instead of a cropped one. Any help on this please?